# How do I include extra files generated by a custom target in the output?

Tags: msbuild

What is the correct way to tell MSBuild a file generated by a custom target is an output file for this project so it is included in the output of other projects that reference this one?

I have a custom target that generates a .tlb COM+ type library file. The target is in projA. It generates the file, which shows up in the output folder (i.e., bin\Debug\net472) as expected.

But when I reference projA in a second project, projB, the .tlb file is missing in projB's output. All the other files generated when building projA are present in projB, including the .dll and .pdb files. But the .tlb file is missing.

This is my target:

```
  <Target Name="GenerateTypeLibraries" AfterTargets="Build" DependsOnTargets="Build"
          Outputs="$(TargetName).tlb"
          Condition="'$(GenerateTypeLibOnBuild)' == 'true'">
    <PropertyGroup>
      <TlbFile>$(TargetName).tlb</TlbFile>
      <TlbFullPath>$(TargetDir)$(TlbFile)</TlbFullPath>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <Exec Command='"$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\..\..\MSBuild\Tools\tlbexp.exe" "$(TargetDir)$(TargetFileName)" /out:"$(TlbFullPath)"' />
  </Target>
```

In projA's project file, I set the `GenerateTypeLibOnBuild` property:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    ...
    <GenerateTypeLibOnBuild>true</GenerateTypeLibOnBuild>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

I thought the `Outputs="$(TargetName).tlb"` was supposed to tell MSBuild that this file was an output of the build process, but that doesn't seem to be working.

What is the correct way to tell MSBuild the new file is an output file for this project so it is included in the output of other projects that reference this one?

**UPDATE 1:**

[This looks like essentially the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41121527/how-to-add-files-to-a-projects-output-files-from-an-msbuild-task), but the answer there didn't work. I added this to the end of my target in projA, after the `<Exec ... />` tag:

```
  <Target ...>
    ...
    <Exec ... />
    <ItemGroup>
      <AllItemsFullPathWithTargetPath Include="$(TlbFullPath)">
        <TargetPath>$(TlbFile)</TargetPath>
        <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      </AllItemsFullPathWithTargetPath>
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>
```

That does not make the generated file copy to projB's output folder when projB builds. (Which makes sense, because I think the ItemGroup is local to the target if it's declared inside that target? But maybe I'm wrong about that.)

**UPDATE 2:**

I am still looking for an answer to this. What I have right now feels like a hack. I have the above target that generates the .tlb file when compiling projA, along with a corresponding target to clean up the .tlb file after the AfterClean target runs. And then I have yet another pair of targets in projB that copy any .tlb files that happen to have been generated.

But this doesn't feel like the right way to do it, since the standard set of targets know how to copy all the other files generated as project output when I reference projA from projB. Also, this isn't a good solution, because my projA is really not just one project; it's about 50 projects. Long story short, my hack works right now, but it is fragile and I'm concerned it will cause other problems down the road.

I'd really like to have a better answer to this, and I'd be surprised if there isn't one.

What is the right way to write a target that generates additional project output so the MSBuild system understands how to include it in downstream projects?

Comment: "I think the ItemGroup is local to the target if it's declared inside that target?" -- That's not correct; all items are defined at the level of the project and there's not really any "scoping" in MSBuild.

Comment: Okay, thanks for correcting that misconception. I'm not sure what I read that led me to that understanding, so thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I'd keep things simple and add the tlb as `Content` instead of trying things which are likely not supported (e.g. just overwriting AllItemsFullPathWithTargetPath, or in this case the other way around: having AllItemsFullPathWithTargetPath overwritten by MSBuild because it is meant to be calculated and not set by the project).

At the end of your project (*after* the Microsoft.CSharp.targets import because that one computes TargetName):

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <TlbFullPath>$(IntermediateOutputPath)$(TargetName).tlb</TlbFullPath>
</PropertyGroup>
<ItemGroup>
  <Content Include="$(TlbFullPath)">
    <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
  </Content>
</ItemGroup>
<Target Name="GenerateTypeLibraries" AfterTargets="Compile" Outputs="$(TlbFullPath)">
  <!-- Replace with actual tlb generation -->
  <WriteLinesToFile File="$(TlbFullPath)" Lines="AAAAA" />
</Target>
```

> I thought the Outputs="$(TargetName).tlb" was supposed to tell MSBuild that this file was an output of the build proces

This is what it does: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-targets?view=vs-2019#incremental-builds